# Portibility concern in a c# and ado.net application

Tags: c#, ado.net

greetings to all the members for taking time to read this question.

I am preparing an application for a quiz system that will take random questions from the database and put them in the interface(c#) using ado.net.

My question is i want the program to be portable , i.e yout dont have to install completely the sql server on all the systems i will run my code (if i user sql server drivers).

What is the solution for this problem ??

Answer (score 4):

You may choose [Sql CE](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx) (Compact) database.

Blog from [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx) :

> SQL CE does not require you to run a setup or install a database
>   server in order to use it.  You can simply copy the SQL CE binaries
>   into the \bin directory of your ASP.NET application, and then your web
>   application can use it as a database engine.  No setup or extra
>   security permissions are required for it to run. You do not need to
>   have an administrator account on the machine. Just copy your web
>   application onto any server and it will work. This is true even of
>   medium-trust applications running in a web hosting environment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SQL Server.

You can use a database like [SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) that can be used via ADO.NET and distributed with your application instead of requiring a separate database installation.

Note that this approach may or may not be enough for your actual database needs.

Answer (score 0):

I like AVD's answer and is probably the way to go, but using linq to XML would be a good alternative for portability.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your DataSet as a binary file.

```
DataSet ds = GetData();
ds.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;
BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
bin.Serialize(stream, ds);
```